# UISlider set value

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uislider, uianimation

I have a UISlider and I want to set its value from 1 to 10. The code I use is.

```
let slider = UISlider()
slider.value = 1.0
// This works I know that
slider.value = 10.0
```

What I want to do is animate the UISlider so that it takes 0.5s to change. I don't want it to be as jumpy more smooth.

My idea so far is.

```
let slider = UISlider()
slider.value = 1.0
// This works I know that
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animation: { slider.value = 10.0 } completion: nil)
```

I am looking for the solution in Swift.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `UISlider`? There is a method for setting a value with animation.

Comment: This question is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539913/uiview-animatewithduration-not-working-with-uislider except that answer (as simple as it is) is in Objective-C.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for everything I feel like you have answered multiple questions for me. Your very generous with your time and helping people on here and I appreciate that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIView animateWithDuration not working with UISlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539913/uiview-animatewithduration-not-working-with-uislider)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDITED**

After some discussion, I thought I'd clarify the differences between the two suggested solutions:

1. Using the built-in UISlider method `.setValue(10.0, animated: true)`.
2. Encapsulating this method in a `UIView.animateWithDuration`.

Since the author is asking explicitly for a change that will take 0.5s---possibly triggered by another action---the second solution is to prefer.

As an example, consider that a button is connected to an action that sets the slider to its maximum value.

```
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Method 1: no animation in this context
    slider.setValue(10.0, animated: true)

    // Method 2: animates the transition, ok!
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.slider.setValue(10.0, animated: true) },
        completion: nil)
}
```

Running a simple single `UIVIewController` app with just the `UISlider` and `UIButton` objects present yields the following results.

- [Method 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HFhv.gif): Instant slide (even though `animated: true`)
- [Method 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww2xt.gif): Animates transition. Note that if we set `animated: false` in this context, the transition will be instantaneous.

Comment: Why not just use the method provided by `UISlider` to animate the value change?

Comment: Thanks guys I found it and the answer has been edited.

Comment: There is no reason to use `setValue:animated:` inside the `UIView animateWithDuration` block.

Answer (score 2):

the problem with @dfri's answer is that the blue Minimum Tracker is moving from 100% to the value, so in order to solve that, you need to change the method a little bit:

```
extension UISlider
{
  ///EZSE: Slider moving to value with animation duration
  public func setValue(value: Float, duration: Double) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
      self.setValue(self.value, animated: true)

      }) { (bol) -> Void in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
          self.setValue(value, animated: true)
          }, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}
```